# How to port blowfish decryption from python to java?

Tags: java, python, blowfish

So i have a python2 impl of blowfish decrypt:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import Blowfish

decodee = '1234'
key = 'oY3[r.Ri4oF'
IV = '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

res = Blowfish.new(key=key, mode=Blowfish.MODE_CFB, IV=IV).decrypt(decodee)
print len(res), map(ord, list(res))
```

with output

```
4 [124, 91, 187, 19]
```

I tried to port it to java like this:

```
String decodee = "1234";
String key = "oY3[r.Ri4oF";
String iv = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";

SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "Blowfish");
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CFB/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

byte[] res = cipher.doFinal(decodee.getBytes());
String s = new String(res);  
int[] x = new int[s.length()]; for (int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++) x[i] = (int) s.charAt(i);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
```

but it shows:

```
4 [124, 242, 10, 112]
```

How to make it equals?

Comment: To what end are you porting it? You should just use any of the Java implementations of it.

Comment: i use javax.crypto.Cipher, javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec, javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec, ssory for not to mention